# Custom slider offset positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implemented a vertical slider, with two controls (up/next & down/prev) however I can't get it to work right. I'm kind of lost with the slider offset(top/bottom) logic if either of the controls is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<div id="2353165313-gallery" class="product-more-pictures desktop-3">
  <a href="#" class="up">︽</a>
  <div class="gallery-container" style="top: -173px;">
      <a href="#" data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Feature_Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0039_1024x1024.jpg?v=1446136593" data-image-id="5777399809" data-zoom-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Feature_Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0039.jpg?v=1446136593">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Feature_Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0039_compact.jpg?v=1446136593" data-image-id="5777399809" alt="Say It To My Lace Party Dress">
      </a>

      <a href="#" data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0007_1024x1024.jpg?v=1446136608" data-image-id="5777409601" data-zoom-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0007.jpg?v=1446136608">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0007_compact.jpg?v=1446136608" data-image-id="5777409601" alt="Say It To My Lace Party Dress">
      </a>

      <a href="#" data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0086_1024x1024.jpg?v=1446136624" data-image-id="5777420225" data-zoom-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0086.jpg?v=1446136624">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0086_compact.jpg?v=1446136624" data-image-id="5777420225" alt="Say It To My Lace Party Dress">
      </a>

      <a href="#" data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0092_1024x1024.jpg?v=1446136640" data-image-id="5777431617" data-zoom-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0092.jpg?v=1446136640">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0092_compact.jpg?v=1446136640" data-image-id="5777431617" alt="Say It To My Lace Party Dress">
      </a>

      <a href="#" data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0104_1024x1024.jpg?v=1446136662" data-image-id="5777446593" data-zoom-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0104.jpg?v=1446136662">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Say_it_to_My_Lace_Party_Dress_0104_compact.jpg?v=1446136662" data-image-id="5777446593" alt="Say It To My Lace Party Dress">
      </a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="down active">︾</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.product-more-pictures a {
  display: block;
}

.product-more-pictures {
  text-align: right;
  height: 462px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 104px;
}

.gallery-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

.gallery-container img {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.product-more-pictures .up,
.product-more-pictures .down {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0px 0px 4px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 80;
}

.product-more-pictures .up { top: 0px; }
.product-more-pictures .down {
  bottom: 0px; 
  padding-top: 10px;
  line-height: .9;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var the_offset = 0;
var image_height = 0;
var gallery_offset = 0;
var image_count = $('img.thumbnail').length;
var click_count = 0;

$('.product-more-pictures .down').click(function() {
    image_height = jQuery(this).parent().find('img.thumbnail').height() + 7;
    gallery_offset = $(".gallery-container").css("top").replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    the_offset = gallery_offset ? parseInt(gallery_offset) + parseInt(image_height) : image_height;

    if(the_offset <= image_height * image_count - 1   ) {
        $(".gallery-container").animate({'top': '-' + the_offset + 'px' })
        click_count = click_count + 1;
    }
});

$('.product-more-pictures .up').click(function() {
    var hidden_items = parseInt(image_height) * click_count - 1;
    $(".gallery-container").animate({'top': the_offset - hidden_items + 'px' });
    click_count = click_count - 1;

});
```

Here's the fiddle of the custom vertical slider: https://jsfiddle.net/k6uba9v2/1/

Comment: Can you describe what the intended behavior should be? It looks like the bottom control works fine, but then if you go all the way to the bottom and click up, all the pictures scroll off screen. In any event, I'd rethink your code structure. When a user clicks the bottom button, it seems like you should grab the picture whose height + offset.top is greater than the viewport height (e.g. the picture is out of range or clipped by the viewport), then increase the scrollTop position of the list accordingly. vice versa for the up button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion based on your code.
For it to work, you need to set the `.gallery-container` `top` to `0` (maybe better if you move that to your CSS).

A link to a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/k6uba9v2/4/) with this suggestion.

```
jQuery(function () {
    var gallery_offset = 0;
    var image_count = $('img.thumbnail').length;
    var click_count = 0;
    var image_height = jQuery('.thumbnail').parent().outerHeight();

    $('.product-more-pictures .down').click(function () {
        if (click_count < image_count - 1) {
            click_count = click_count + 1;
            update_gallery();
        }
    });

    $('.product-more-pictures .up').click(function () {
        if (click_count > 0) {
            click_count = click_count - 1;
            update_gallery();
        }
    });

    function update_gallery() {
        gallery_offset = click_count * image_height;
        $(".gallery-container").animate({
            'top': '-' + gallery_offset + 'px'
        });
    }
});
```